# Array initializer is not allowed(replica of minesweeper)

Tags: java, arrays, intellij-idea, minesweeper

```
import java.util.*;
class sweep {
    static String boardZero[][] = new String[10][21];

    sweep() {
        boardZero[10][21] = {{"|", "1", "|", "2", "|", "3", "|", "4", "|", "5", "|", "6", "|", "7", "|", "8", "|", "9", "|", "10", "|"}, {"|", "11", "|", "12", "|", "13", "|", "14", "|", "15", "|", "16", "|", "17", "|", "18", "|", "19", "|", "20", "|"}, {"|", "21", "|", "22", "|", "23", "|", "24", "|", "25", "|", "26", "|", "27", "|", "28", "|", "29", "|", "30", "|"}, {"|", "31", "|", "32", "|", "33", "|", "34", "|", "35", "|", "36", "|", "37", "|", "38", "|", "39", "|", "40", "|"}, {"|", "41", "|", "42", "|", "43", "|", "44", "|", "45", "|", "46", "|", "47", "|", "48", "|", "49", "|", "50", "|"}, {"|", "51", "|", "52", "|", "53", "|", "54", "|", "55", "|", "56", "|", "57", "|", "58", "|", "59", "|", "60", "|"}, {"|", "61", "|", "62", "|", "63", "|", "64", "|", "65", "|", "66", "|", "67", "|", "68", "|", "69", "|", "70", "|"}, {"|", "71", "|", "72", "|", "73", "|", "74", "|", "75", "|", "76", "|", "77", "|", "78", "|", "79", "|", "80", "|"}, {"|", "81", "|", "82", "|", "83", "|", "84", "|", "85", "|", "86", "|", "87", "|", "88", "|", "89", "|", "90", "|"}, {"|", "91", "|", "92", "|", "93", "|", "94", "|", "95", "|", "96", "|", "97", "|", "98", "|", "99", "|", "100", "|"}};
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    }
}
```

I am trying to replicate the minesweeper program in the form of cui in java. But it is showing the error `"Array initializer is not allowed".`

I have tried all other methods of initialization including initializing in the main method.

So, I don't know what to do next.

P.S. `boardZero` means the reset board.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That syntax is allowed only in variable declarations. So, when it's: `String[][] board = ....`, not when it's just `board =`. Then you need: `new String[][] {{....}}` (put `new String[][]`  in front).

Additionally, `boardZero[10][21]` is referring to a single 'slot' in your array: The 22nd item in the 11th array of `boardZero`, which is an array of string arrays. You can't assign an array-of-arrays to a single slot, you can only assign a single string here. Presumably you want: `boardZero = new String[][] {{...}};`

Comment: `static String[][] boardZero=new String[10][21]{{"|","1","|","2","|","3","|","4","|","5","|","6","|","7","|","8","|","9","|","10","|"},......};` It still shows the same error.

Comment: Nope, works fine in every java I have. You've messed up something else and you'd need to update your paste if you need SO to help you out.